# Magic 8 ball program loop?

Tags: java, random, while-loop

I have created a simple magic 8 ball program. But the issue is every single time I compile my program and run the loop the loop keeps on repeating the same random answer. The issue is not about the loop going on forever its when I compile it and run it, the program gives a random answer but keeps on repeating the same answer till i recompile the file.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Moreloopex4 {

    public Moreloopex4() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Declaring Random
        Random rand = new Random();

        // Declaring scanner
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System. in );

        // Declaring variables
        String input;
        int randnum;

        // Declaring randomizer
        randnum = rand.nextInt(6) + 0;

        // Conditional Statements
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Enter your statement");
            input = scan.nextLine();
            if (randnum == 0) {
                System.out.println("Without a doubt ");
            }
            else if (randnum == 1) {
                System.out.println("I cannot predict now");
            }
            else if (randnum == 2) {
                System.out.println("My sources say no");
            }
            else if (randnum == 3) {
                System.out.println("Signs point to yes");
            }
            else if (randnum == 4) {
                System.out.println("Don't count on it");
            }
            else if (randnum == 5) {
                System.out.println("Better not tell you now");
            }
            else if (randnum == 6) {
                System.out.println("Yes, definetly");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Format your code properly, please. 2) Put the line `randnum = rand.nextInt(6)+0;` inside of the `while` loop.

Comment: put `randnum = rand.nextInt(6)+0;` inside your `while` loop

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but will greatly cleanup your code: Instead of using that big `if`/`else` statement with the duplicated calls to `System.out.println`, you should put your strings in a `String[]` array, and then just index into it with like `MESSAGES[randnum]`. This way, you only have one single call to `System.out.println()` and no `if`/`else`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: What's the point of `+ 0`?

Comment: My range is supposed to go from 0 to 6

Comment: try printing rand.nextInt(6) in a for loop that repeats say, fifty times and see what happens

Answer (score 2):

You are only assigning one random value, here:

```
randnum = rand.nextInt(6) + 0;
```

outside of your loop, then referencing the defined variable from inside of the loop.

What you want to do is call a new random number each time you need one, which is each time your while loop repeats. You would move the above line to the inside of your while loop.

Comment: Also is my range in randnum correct. My range should be from 0 to 6

Comment: @AbhayRaina Make the suggested change and see what happens.

Comment: No problem! Thank you for choosing StackOverflow!

Answer (score 2):

You are only setting the randnum variable once, so it will continue to use that value unless you set it again within your while loop.   Just declaring it once does not continue to get a new random number every time you check randnum.  You need to get a new value inside of your while loop by assigning it to rand.nextInt(6) again.

This code

```
...
randnum = rand.nextInt(6)+0;

// Conditional Statements
while(true)
{

...
```

Becomes this

```
...

// Conditional Statements
while(true)
{

    randnum = rand.nextInt(6)+0;
...
```